# turning regular expression object into something readable

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I am trying mutate a dictionary so that the value representing regular expression patterns are replaced by their patterns so for example if

```
p = dict(digit='\\d', integer='[+-]?#digit##digit#*')
```

then calling `expand_re(p)` will return the following dictionary

```
{'integer': '[+-]?(\\d)(\\d)*', 'digit': '\\d'}.
```

Here is what I have so far

```
def expand_re(pat_dict:{str:str})-> None: #{names: RE pattern}    
    #Mutates dictionary by repeatedly replacing each name by its pattern in all the rules 
    # [+-]#digit##digit#*' -> '[+-]?(\\d)(\\d)*'

    for key, value in pat_dict.items():

        subbed = re.sub('#','', value)
        compiled = re.compile(subbed)
        print(compiled)
        pat_dict[key] = compiled

    return pat_dict 


pd = dict(digit=r'\d', integer=r'[=-]?#digit##digit#*')
print(expand_re(pd))
```

when I print compiled it just prints `<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x026E2020>` how can the digit string in the value for integer be replaced by `//d`? Isn't that the purpose for compile ?

Comment: You have a compiled regular expression, that's what the `<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0xhhhhhh>` *means*. I am not certain what you expected to happen instead here.

Comment: Actually, why are you compiling the patterns at all? Your code comment implies that you want to adjust the `integer` **string** to replace patterns in that.

Comment: I basically just want to replace the names in the dictionarys values (that are between #) with their associated patterns being inside parenthesis, but for some reason I was thinking compile would automatically do that after reading over the string

Comment: No, `re.compile()` compiles a pattern *as is*; it doesn't do any substitutions.

Comment: is there a method that reads over a string (such as digit) in this one and finds the match replacing it with \\d?

Comment: Sure, use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec); `integer=r'[=-]?{digit}{digit}*'`, then `pd['integer'] = pd['integer'].format(**pd)` would work.

Comment: how many substitutions do you expect to happen? Are transitional substitutions supported? E.g., if you have`dict(digit=r'\d', `phone=r'{digit}+', contact=r'\w+: {phone}')`, `phone` uses `digit` indirectly.